# C++ Pointer of Array of Ints Initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, fill

I want to have an array accessible by all functions of a class.

I put the array as private variable in the header file.

```
    private:
    int* arrayName;
```

In the .cpp file where I implement the class, the constructor takes in an int value (size) and creates the array. The goal is to fill it up

```
ClassName::ClassName(int numElements){
  arrayName = new int[numElements]; //make arrays the size of numElements
  for(int i = 0; i<numElements; i++)
      arrayName[i] = 0;
}
```

I feel like this is quite inefficient. I know you can do int array[5] = {0}; but how do you do it when you don't initially know the size.

Comment: Your private variable is just a pointer. Not an array, not a pointer to an array.

Comment: Something has to zero the memory; whether it's you or a library function. There's no way to magically zero memory without iterating it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to zero-initialize a newed array, just do *value-initialize* it. This has the effect of zero-initializing its elements:

```
arrayName = new int[numElements]();
//                              ^^
```

But you really want to be using an `std::vector<int>`.

```
private:
  std::vector<int> vname;
```

and

```
ClassName::ClassName(int numElements) : vname(numElements) {}
```

This way you don't have to worry about deleting an array and implementing copy constructors and assignment operators.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `memset` function:

```
memset(arrayName,0,sizeof(int)*numElements);
```

This `void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );` function sets the first num bytes of the block of memory pointed by `ptr` to the specified value (interpreted as an unsigned char).

To use it you must include the `string.h` header file.

For more information: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is progressively expand the array on demand.

```
 arrayName = new int[numElements];
 for(int i = 0; i<numElements; i++)
       arrayName[i] = 0;
```

The above code (what you gave) will give you an array of size numElements, and THEN the for loop will fill it. This is allocated now, and can't, as I understand it, be simply or easily resized (memset will overwrite previously held values in the array).

You could copy the whole array over every time you want to resize it:

```
 int * oldarr = new int[OldSize];
 //fill your old array

 int * newarr = new int[NewSize];
 for(int i = 0; i<OldSize; i++)
       newarr[i] = oldarr[i];
```

Other than that, you could make the array much larger, or you could use various STLs, such as std::vector. Vector can be increased with a simple push_back function, and allows [] operator access (like arr[5] and whatnot).

Hope this helps!